# Rxjs refCount callback to cleanup once every subscribers have unsubscribed?

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I've got an observable which is not long lived (http request).

I'm using `publishReplay(1)` and `refCount()` so that when there an attempt to access it at the same time, it'll return the same value without triggering the http call again.

But if all the subscriptions are unsubscribed, I need to make some cleanup.

I can't use `finalize` because:

- if I use it before `publishReplay` then it get closed once the http request is done
- if I use it after `refCount` it'll be run as soon as one observable unsubscribe (instead of when all have unsubscribed)

So basically what I'd like would be to pass a callback to `refCount` and call that callback when the number of subscriptions reaches 0. But it doesn't work like that. Is there any way to be "warned" when all the subscribers have unsubscribed?

The simplest way I can think of right now would be to create a custom operator that'd pretty much extend `refCount` to add a callback.

Any better thoughts? I'm pretty sure that there's a better way of doing that.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not place it between `publishReplay` and `refCount`? If `ConnectableObservable` implements  `lift`, `finalize` will return a `ConnectableObservable` - allowing `refCount` to be used. This cannot be represented using TypeScript, but it's what `lift` does.

Comment: Oh really cool I thought I had an error doing that but turns out I don't! Thanks for the explanation @cartant if you've got 1mn rewrite that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not gonna lie, I was happy to find out I wasn't the only one looking for something like that. There is one another person.

I ended up doing something like that:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export function tapTeardown(teardownLogic: () => void) {
  return <T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
    new Observable<T>((observer) => {
      const subscription = source.subscribe(observer);

      return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        teardownLogic();
      };
    });
}
```

And you use it like:

```js
    const augmented = connection.pipe(
      tapTeardown(() => /* SOME TEARDOWN LOGIC */),
      shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it and it seems to work correctly.

Here's how it's used:

```
import { of, timer } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, publishReplay, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { refCountCb } from './refCountCb';

const source = timer(2000, 10000).pipe(
  map(x => `Hello ${x}!`),
  publishReplay(1),
  refCountCb(() => console.log('MAIN CLOSED'))
);

source.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
source.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Output:

```
Hello 0!
Hello 0!
MAIN CLOSED
```

I've built the custom `refCountCb` operator based on the [source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/df0ea7c78767c07a6ed839608af5a7bb4cefbde5/src/internal/operators/refCount.ts) of `refCount`. It's basically just adding a callback so I won't copy paste the whole code here but it's available on the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-h7dbfc?file=refCountCb.ts).

Full demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-h7dbfc?file=index.ts

If you have any other idea please share it, I'd be glad to discover different solutions!